# How to associate a function to a tab in a tab set?

Tags: html, angular

Hi I'm in a angular 2 environment and I want to associate a function from the typescript file to a tab selection so I want know what is the keyword for this:

So far I've tried onClick, onSelect, select. Any idea?
Thanks

```
        <tabset>
      <tab title="Day" (click)="showDay()">
        <br/>
      </tab>
      <tab title="Week" (click)="showWeek()">
        <br/>
      </tab>
      <tab title="Month" (click)="showMonth()">
        <br/>
      </tab>
      <tab title="Quarter" (click)="showQuarter()">
        <br/>
      </tab>
      <tab title="Year" (click)="showYear()">
        <br/>
      </tab>
    </tabset>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Angular directives.
As I remember it should be something like "ng-click".

Comment: Thanks but I tried this one too and it doesn't work.

Comment: @DTerio create a fiddle or snippet showing your angular code as well as your html and css so we can see where you are going wrong. `ng-click` should work, unless you haven't set up your controller, methods or scopes properly.

Comment: I finally used <onSelect="onSelectTab($event)"> where event return the index of the selected tab starting at index 0.